# embedded http server on android to server assets folder

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using an **embedded http server** from the following example on

https://github.com/nikkiii/embedhttp

The http server code is initiated as

```
File filesDir = getFilesDir();
HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
server.addRequestHandler(new HttpStaticFileHandler(new File("."))); 
server.addRequestHandler(new HttpStaticFileHandler(filesDir));
server.bind(8081);
// Start the server thread
server.start();
```

The http server is embedded so as to serve a www folder from the server as `http://localhost:8081/folderpath/index.html` . Then in turn I will be using WebView to access the localhost url.

In **webview** I try to access.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("`http://localhost:8081/`");
  myWebView.loadUrl("`http://localhost:8081/index.html`");
  myWebView.loadUrl("`http://localhost:8081/www/index.html`");
  myWebView.loadUrl("`http://localhost:8081/assets/www/index.html`");
```

But none of them work. What is the probable solution to such a situation where the assets/www flder needs to be served from localhost running on android. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android `assets` folder is not available via `getFilesDir()`: `getFilesDir()` returns a different directory. To serve resources in the assets folder you'll need to use `AssetManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) and do a little translation from your request paths to the appropriate resource.